# Digital library of implicit curves and surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, visualization, implicit-function

I am implemented a small program for visualization implicit curves and surfaces. But I can not find enough examples for testing.

Can you advice a site who contains a large number 
of various and interesting of implicit function?

This site must be display equations in list format with plot images. [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/interesting-implicit-surfaces-in-mathbbr3)

Answer (score 1):

Try these surface galleries; there are many others around:

- http://surf.sourceforge.net/gallery.shtml
- https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/bildergalerie/gallery.html
- https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/gallery.html
- https://danielleamethyst.org/gallery/hauser/
- https://imaginary.org/gallery/algebraic-surfaces
- https://imaginary.org/program/surfer

Comment: This galleries do not contain a implicit curves(surfaces only)

Comment: @PavelDev, well, setting one of the variables to a constant values gives lots of implicit curves...